# String concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, constants

if I want to construct a `const char *` out of several primitive type arguments, is there a way to build the string using a similar to the `printf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking for [snprintf](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html).

`int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);`

A simple example:

```
char buffer[100];
int value = 42;
int nchars = snprintf(buffer, 100, "The answer is %d", value);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
/* outputs: The answer is 42 */
```

[GNU has an example too](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#index-snprintf-1032).

Just to add, you don't actually need to use `snprintf` - you can use the plain old `sprintf` (without the size argument) but then it is more difficult to ensure only *n* characters are written to the buffer. GNU also has a nice function, [`asprintf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool//manual/libc/Dynamic-Output.html) which will allocate the buffer for you.

Comment: +1 Neat, that page for `asprintf` led to the [Obstack](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool//manual/libc/Obstacks.html) documentation, which looks pretty useful in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sprintf, which is exactly like printf except the first parameter is a buffer where the string will be placed.

Example:

```
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer, "Hello, %s!\n", "Beta");
```

Comment: i think you mean sprintf, fprintf prints to files

Comment: Also, use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf`.

Comment: ah yes.  as far as I recall, fprintf takes a `fd` not an actual pointer.

Comment: @Mechko: `fprintf` takes a `FILE*`, not a file descriptor, although you can obtain a `FILE*` from a file descriptor easily enough by calling `fdopen`.